# Posting Radiobuttonfor to different boolean fields whilst grouping then using name property returns null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, radio-button

I have radiobuttons nested within two for loops, they are for a quiz and only one radiobutton should be selected for each question, here is the second for loop where the radiobutton is:

```
for (int k = 0; k < Model[i].QuizAnswers.Count(); k++)
            {
                <li>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].QuizAnswers[k].Correct)
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model[i].QuizAnswers[k].Chosen, true, new { id = "radioanswer", @Name = "N-" + @Model[i].Order, data_questionid = @Model[i].Order })
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model[i].QuizAnswers[k].Answer)
                </li>
            }
```

In order to stop the user selecting multiple radiobuttons I have grouped the name attribute for each set of radiobuttons as above.  Each Radiobutton is posting true to an individual boolean field.  Without the grouped name attribute the radiobuttons post correctly, however with the grouped name attribute they do not post.  I'm guessing this is because by grouping the buttons using the name attribute MVC assumes they all should be returning to a single field.  How can I fix this so that the Radiobuttons return true to their individual fields whilst at the same time being grouped so that only one can be selected?

Edit - As requested my models are as follows, the view model the radio buttons are posted too:

```
public class QuizViewModel
{
    public int QuizQuestionID { get; set; }
    public int QuizID { get; set; }
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int OldCoursePageID { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public IList<QuizAnswers> QuizAnswers { get; set; }
}
```

The QuizAnswers model within the viewmodel above:

```
public class QuizAnswers
{
    [Key]
    public int QuizAnsID { get; set; }
    public int QuizQuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool Correct { get; set; }
    public bool Chosen { get; set; }

    public virtual QuizQuestions QuizQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Whats the actual property your trying to bind to? And all you radio button have a value of `true` which does not make sense. You need to show your models

Comment: I've added the models involved.  The radio buttons are binding to the chosen boolean property.  The reason it has worked out like this is because other questions use checkbox's and multiple answers, so i've ended up using a controller action that works out the score by checking the chosen against the correct boolean.

Comment: Your `QuizViewModel` needs a property for the selected answer so that you can use `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { foreach (var answer in Model[i].QuizAnswers) { @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].SelectedAnswer, answer.QuizAnsID) } }` and the `SelectedAnswer` will contain the `QuizAnsID` of the selected radio button

Comment: The only way it could work with your current model structure is to use a `CheckBoxFor()` for `Chosen` and then use some javascript to ensure only one of the `QuizAnswers` can be selected in a question

Comment: Thanks Stephen, yes that's how I originally had it using a field in the viewmodel for the radiobuttons called selectedanswer.  I modified this so that each radiobutton did the same thing as a checkbox so that the action where the score was counted was neater, thinking I could just group the Radio buttons by name,  Unfortunately it seems I can't, I think I'll go the javascript route.  Thanks.

Comment: Suggest wrap the checkboxes for a question in a container (`<div>`), and handle the `.click()` event of all relevant checkboxes. If its `:checked`, then set the `.prop('checked', false)` of all its siblings (i.e. within the container)